# Can Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() parsing be reused?

Tags: c#

Can [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() parsing method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) be reused without actually rewriting it? Is it exposed anywhere else in .NET?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can put the arguments into a global variable and use them wherever you need them.

Comment: I need to test parsing with several values and see if it works for my needs or use it for custom strings to break them apart.

Comment: so you want to reuse the logic that transforms the string to a string[]?

Comment: @rene Indeed. Found the solution and added as an answer. I need to get used to looking at the .NET reference code more.

Answer (score 2):

*Silly me! Should've Googled harder.*

So on the [.NET reference site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) I looked at [the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,84c2c7cb5c89246f) and the parser is actually a native call.

Then remembered the [`Win32 CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) function. And [PInvoke came to the rescue](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.commandlinetoargvw).

Just gotta test now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I entirely follow your question. However

Environment is generally available in winforms, and console apps. So will be available as a whole anywhere in any of those type of apps. If you choose. So you wouldnt need to do any extra work to make it available.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing a custom string to command line arguments parser for custom strings by using the built in one.

Comment: If you can make your command line options not require extra work, then no you wont need to make your life harder, the commandline args are available as part of that environment class. it